# Error message pops up every time I start Excel - how to get rid of it?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I am using Excel 2007 at work. A few months ago I wrote a VBA script which referenced some files on our network drive.  Ever since that day, whenever I fire up Excel (any file, not just the file I was working with), I get this message:

> \(network file path)(dir)\test.csv' could not be found. Check the
>   spelling of the file name, and verify that the file location is
>   correct.
>
> If you are trying to open the file from your list of most recently
>   used files, make sure that the file has not been renamed, moved, or
>   deleted.

The file it's referencing was a test file we used to debug, and it has been deleted. I noticed that if I add the file back to its location, the error goes away (which makes sense, since it can now find the file).  But, it seems very odd to me that every time I start Excel it does a query for that file.  Any ideas on how to stop this behavior?

Comment: Do you have an Auto_Open or Workbook_Open macro in your personal.xlsm file? Or maybe in your "At Startup, open all files in" there is a path there?

Comment: @Jim I see the error for all workbooks, with or without VBA code.

Comment: @JP. not using a personal .xlsm file, "at startup open all files in" folder is empty and not used...

Comment: Nothing is visible in the VB Editor? Nothing referenced in Add-ins?

Comment: @datatoo nope, it gives the error even when I open up Excel with a new workbook.  Nothing in VB, no Add-ins.

Answer (score 1):

You say the `at startup open all files in` field is empty, but what about your start folder itself?

While Excel is closed, open Windows Explorer, type this in the address `%appdata%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART` and press enter.

The easty fix would be that XLSTART has a shortcut to the missing file. If so, delete it.

If that didn't fix your problem try temporarily removing all files in XLSTART. (Move them to your desktop or some place easy.) Restart Excel, do you still get the error?

Assuming you don't get the error, open the files you removed from XLSTART one by one to see which one is causing the error.

Comment: not only app data yet this one should also be cleared %localappdata%\Microsoft\Excel\XLStart http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2016/01/solved-excell-xlsm-drive-could-not-be-found-mapped-network-drives-cannot-be-loaded-unc-path-works.html

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found the answer here:

http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/155156-excel-2010-error-popup-while-lauching-or-opening-files/

Go to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Excel\Options" and see if there's a string value for OPEN that has the problem file path in question and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and Excel had installed the file in question as an `Add-in`.

Easy to fix

- *File > Options > Add-ins*
- Select *Manage Add-ins*
- Delete the file in question

It sorts it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, the problem is likely to lie within the length of your filepath.

Follow these steps to solve:

1. Copy the file to desktop to backup from
2. Rename the original file if it has a long name
3. Open it to test whether it has worked.